# Changing titlepage in beamer: background, box, title position

Tags: beamer, titles, backgrounds

After having some issues with Office Word I had to redo my thesis in LaTeX and now I decided to change from power point to beamer as well. However I don't like very much the beamer templates and I'm trying to reproduce a title page that I usually utilize.

I've started with the default setup and have been trying to put in image in the background for start, but I've tried the \usebackgroungtemplate and \titlegrafic commands that I found in some previous questions, but my image doesn't fill the background, or goes to another page, or doesn't show up because I get a "undefined sequence" error. That's the titlepage that I'm trying to reproduce (doesn't have to be exactly the same):

[image: Title page]

Some of the codes I've tried:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}


% Title page details: 
\title{My tests} 
\author{Karina Padula}
\date{}
\logo{}

%background image for title page
    \titlegraphic{%
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{jap-art.png}
}

\begin{document}

% Title page frame
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

or

```
 % Title page frame
{%
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{jap-art.png}}
      \begin{frame}
        \titlepage 
    \end{frame}
}
```

or

```
% Title page frame
{\setbeamertemplate{background}{
\includegraphics[width=\the\paperwidth,height=\the\paperheight]{images/jap-art.jpeg}}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage 
\end{frame}
}
```

And I have not even tried moving the title around and boxing it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are already loading the tikz package, I suggest to use this package to position the image and other elements of your title page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}  
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=white!50!yellow,fg=green!50!black}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[at=(current page.center)]{
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-grid-100x100bp}
    };
    \pgfsetfillopacity{0.6}
    \node[at=(current page.north west),xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm,anchor=north west]{
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[center,sep=0.3cm,dp=-0.1cm,wd=.43\paperwidth]{title}%
        \pgfsetfillopacity{1}%
        \usebeamerfont{title}%
        \inserttitle\par
        \usebeamerfont{author}%
        \insertauthor\par
        \insertdate\par
        \insertinstitute\par
      \end{beamercolorbox}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. 
And if I don't need tikz forr the presentation, is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: @Bags You could manually position the elements or use a picture environment to position your elements.